# How can I restrict a delegating handler to a specific route in Web API?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have a custom delegating handler that manages the authentication of a request. In one of my controllers, authentication should not be enabled for a specific action. How can I disable the delegating handler for the method and route `POST api/MyController`?

One option is to hard code the route inside the handler, however, I would rather keep this logic out of the handler. In addition, I see myself adding this behavior to a few more actions, which can make this method hard to maintain.

```
protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Post
        && request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/api/MyController"))
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    // Do authentication
}
```

Is there a better way that's easier to maintain?

Comment: Not really.  MessageHandlers are intended to apply their behavior consistently to all requests. There is no easy solution applying action filters global and then selectively removing them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When mapping the routes, there is an overload of [MappHttpRoute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj129347%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) that allows you to specify a HttpMessageHandler. You can add your handler to all the routes that need it and omit it for the route that should not use it.
For more information see this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers). The following sample is taken from this resource:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Route1",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Route2",
            routeTemplate: "api2/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: null,
            handler: new MessageHandler2()  // per-route message handler
        );

        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MessageHandler1());  // global message handler
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I restrict http routes by path and method, i.e. `POST` for `/api/MyController`?

Comment: @Omar: good link. An alternative is to apply a HttpPost-attribute to the action method. That also restricts it to accept only POST requests, no matter what the configuration says. Not sure which approach I'd favor.

Comment: Note: I had to use the last code sample from the link http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers. You must do it that way or else requests won't get routed to controllers.

Comment: The seperation of routes from the httpmethod is bit of a guff IMO. You can write your own Attribute that implements IDirectRouteFactory and IActionHttpMethodProvider... I also added a "method" constraint to the route as I was still running into cases where the iactionhttpmethodprovider implementation wasn't... "enough". This was for where I had separate controllers with the same route but a different HTTP method.

Comment: Whats the best way to apply a specific delegating handler to Attribute Routes?